# Link between number of multiplications to calculate n^k and the binary cross sum of n

Tags: haskell, math

Using the identities...

```
       x^0 = 1
    x^(2n) = (x*x)^n
  x^(2n+1) = x * (x*x)^n
```

...we can write a Haskell function that calculates the *k*th power of *x* with fewer than *k* multiplications.

```hs
nat_pow :: Double -> Integer -> Double
nat_pow x 0 = 1
nat_pow x k
  | m==0 = nat_pow (x*x) n            -- k == 2*n  <=>  m == 0
  | otherwise = x * nat_pow (x*x) n   -- k == 2*n+1
  where
    (n,m) = k `divMod` 2              -- n <- k `div` 2; m <- k `mod` 2
```

For example:

```
nat_pow x 6
= nat_pow x^2 3
= x^2 * natpow (x^2)^2 1
= x^2 * (x^2)^2  *  natpow ((x^2)^2)^2) 0
= x^2 * (x^2)^2  *         1
```

Further, we can look at the cross sum of a number w.r.t base 2.

```
crossSum_2 42 = 3                     (because (42)_10 = (101010)_2)
```

**Question:** What is the link between the number of multiplications `nat_pow x k` requires and `crossSum_2 k`?

**What I have so far**:

Let Q(k) be the binary cross sum of k; M(k) the number of multiplications of `nat_pow n k`. Then I can see that

```
M(2k)   = 1 + M(k)
M(2k+1) = 1 + M(2k)

Q(2k)   =     Q(k)
Q(2k+1) = 1 + Q(k)
```

So one could say that

1. Q(n) is the number of "odd" cases of `nat_pow`; hence
2. *M(n) >= Q(n)* always holds.

However, I think there must be more to it.

Comment: Isn't the cruss sum of `42`, `3`?

Comment: Furthermore I actually think this belongs more to [math.SE] or another SX network.

Comment: Hint: what is the relation between the number of ones in a binary representation and the recursions of the last type in your first code fragment?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thats right, fixed it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks for reading, regarding your hint: I see that, just forgot to add it to the post. Anything else you could say about it?

Comment: I have modified two small details in your exposition to be what I believe you intended. Feel free to roll back if you were being precise and I misunderstood.

Comment: And, by the way, there is some fascinating mathematics lurking just around the corner if you're interested. Finding the *minimal* number of multiplications needed to compute an power is surprisingly tricky. Computing the minimal number of multiplications needed to produce a given set of powers [is NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation).

Comment: @DanielWagner thank you for your edits, they were indeed as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> M(2k)   = 1 + M(k)
> M(2k+1) = 1 + M(2k)
>
> Q(2k)   =     Q(k)
> Q(2k+1) = 1 + Q(k)
> ```

In fact, we can make the parallel between the two definitions even closer. In `M(2k+1) = 1 + M(2k)`, we can unroll the equation we have for `M(2k)`:

```
M(2k)   =     1 + M(k)
M(2k+1) = 1 + 1 + M(k)

Q(2k)   =     Q(k)
Q(2k+1) = 1 + Q(k)
```

Now it is clear that, compared to `Q`, `M` adds one more on each "recursive call". So `M(k)` will be `Q(k)` plus the total number of recursive calls `M` makes -- which in this case is also the total number of bits in `k`. (There is just one wrinkle: we haven't written about the base cases for `Q` and `M` above. Once we factor that in, does that change the answer? What would the base cases have to look like in a counterfactual world to give the other answer to "does that change the answer?"?)

Comment: That is nice, since you can express "number of bits" mathematically in terms of "log_2".

It doesn't bother me that it does not hold generally, including base cases -- after all, the recursive definition has explicit base cases so theres bound to be different structure there.

Comment: cf this article: [Number of bits in a decimal integer](http://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-bits-in-a-decimal-integer/)